# HTML Loads Slower in IE8+ Than In Other Browsers

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am loading ten separate dropdown lists with about 13,000 options in each list, but they are all the same data set (all the dropdown lists contain the exact same data). I've verified that the html is the issue and not the code populating them (I saved the resulting html and loaded it directly).

Firefox and Chrome take under a minute to load, and load the lists one by one—you can see them appearing on the screen as they are populated. Internet Explorer 8-11 take 3+ minutes to load the page (at least initially) and only shows a gray screen until it all loads at once, and the browser becomes unresponsive for a little while also (and if you click anywhere it stops responding immediately until the whole page loads).

Why does IE take so much longer to load and not handle this as efficiently as other browsers? Is there anything else I can do to optimize this (most of my user base has IE8-9)?

Comment: I have never heard of that many options in a dropdown list, is that really necessary? Can you instead use an autocompleter? That would present a much nicer user experience: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: (a) because it sucks. (b) Don't load the whole list, or [better] re-dseign the ui/navigation so that the user isn't expected to select from 13,000 items 10 times. The html must be _huge_ Especially since the user has downloaded 129,990 items that they don't want.

Comment: Who is going to search through 13000 options to select the one they want?

Comment: I'll have to consider the autocomplete, but only if I can get the javascript files locally since otherwise it gives the silly 'some contents delivered unsecurely warning'.

Comment: You can create local copies of the javascript instead of using a CDN, if that's what you mean. You will need to stand up a web service to work with the autocomplete, however.

Comment: I don't see how this will work because the code is dependent on getting ID values from the dropdowns passed server side.

Comment: @ChrisHardie is there an example where I can specify both the label and the value? I need to use PK index values but show the user a description/label of each? Preferably one that populates this with ASP.NET/VB and then passes the IDs back from Javascript to ASP.NET once selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could display an image of the list at first to make it look like it is there until the full list is actually loaded then remove the image. Or allow the list to load over the image and as they begin loading, they would be clickable links. Then remove the image once that is finished...

I like the autoComplete idea better though

It is bc ie 8 sucks though

Comment: I (finally) accepted this as an answer mostly because of the last sentence, which I believe fully answers the question: "It is [because Internet Explorer 8] sucks though".